# Python ngram calculation

Tags: python

Using Python [ngram](http://packages.python.org/ngram/index.html). My code looks like this:

```
from ngram import NGram
print(NGram.compare("coat","hat",N=1))
```

The result is 0.4, calculated as follows (I think!):

```
(a-b)/a
```

Where:

```
a = total number of distinct ngrams across the two strings
b = number of ngrams NOT shared by the two strings
```

Plugging in the values from my code this equals:

```
(5-3)/5 = 2/5 = 0.4
```

If I change the code to this:

```
from ngram import NGram
print(NGram.compare("coata","hata",N=1))
```

The result is 0.5 and I'm not sure how this answer comes about from the formula I've written above.

```
(6-3)/6
```

That gives 0.5, but are there really 6 distinct ngrams across the two strings?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Check out the source at https://github.com/gpoulter/python-ngram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "hata", "coat" example, the grams look like this:

```
{'a': {'hata': 2, 'coata': 2}, 
'h': {'hata': 1}, 
'c': {'coata': 1}, 
't': {'hata': 1, 'coata': 1}, 
'o': {'coata': 1}}
```

So, it double weights the `'a'`.

Hence the 3 out of 6.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex, real-world example -

```
from ngram import NGram

S1 = "bronchopneumonia"
S2 = "pneumonia"
N = 1

print(NGram.compare(S1,S2,N))
```

The result is 0.5625

Formula:

```
(x-y)/x
```

Where:

```
x = total number of distinct ngrams across the two strings
y = number of ngrams NOT shared by the two strings
```

Calculation, showing a running total for x and y:

```
 'b': {'bronchopneumonia': 1} x=1, y=1
 'r': {'bronchopneumonia': 1} x=2, y=2
 'o': {'bronchopneumonia': 3, 'pneumonia':1} x=5, y=4 
 'n': {'bronchopneumonia': 3, 'pneumonia':2} x=8, y=5 
 'c': {'bronchopneumonia': 1} x=9, y=6
 'h': {'bronchopneumonia': 1} x=10, y=7
 'p': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=11, y=7
 'e': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=12, y=7
 'u': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=13, y=7
 'm': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=14, y=7
 'i': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=15, y=7
 'a': {'bronchopneumonia': 1, 'pneumonia':1} x=16, y=7
```

Which gives us:

```
(16-7)/16 = 9/16 = 0.5625
```

The complexity arises when you hit an ngram that appears more than once across the two strings. In this example both 'o' and 'n' appear multiple times.

```
'o' appears **3 times** in 'bronchopneumonia' and **1 time** in 'pneumonia'
x now moves to 5 (from 2) and y moves to 4 (from 2).
I think, x is incremented by 3 because it is the higher number???
And I think, y is incremented by 2 because 3-1=2???
```

Similarly for 'n':

```
'n' appears **3 times** in 'bronchopneumonia' and **2 times** in 'pneumonia'
x now moves to 8 (from 5) and y moves to 5 (from 4).
I think, x is incremented by 3 because it is the higher number???
And I think, y is incremented by 1 because 3-2=1???
```

This is my understanding of how it works, I'm not a Python expert so I may have misunderstood something in the source code.